# MySQL Events League JOIN 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables:

events

```
    -----+-------------------+
    | id | eventName         |
    -----+-------------------+
    | 1  | Bowling           |
    | 2  | Quiz              |
    | 3  | Darts             |
    | 4  | Pool              |
    | 5  | Treasure Hunt     |
    | 6  | Snooker           |
    -----+-------------------+
```

competitors

```
    ------+------------------+
    | id  | competitorName   |
    ------+------------------+
    | 1   | Microsoft        |
    | 2   | BBC              |
    | 3   | Facebook         |
    ------+------------------+
```

results

```
    ------+---------------+---------+-------------+
    | id  | competitorId  | eventId |  eventScore |
    ------+---------------+---------+-------------+
    | 1   | 1             |  1      |   12        |
    | 2   | 1             |  2      |   11        |
    | 3   | 1             |  3      |   23        |
    | 4   | 2             |  1      |   66        |
    | 5   | 2             |  2      |   12        |
    | 6   | 2             |  3      |   11        |
    | 7   | 2             |  4      |   23        |
    | 8   | 2             |  5      |   66        |
    | 3   | 2             |  6      |   23        |
    | 4   | 3             |  1      |   66        |
    | 5   | 3             |  2      |   12        |
    | 6   | 3             |  3      |   11        |
    | 7   | 3             |  4      |   23        |
    | 8   | 3             |  6      |   66        |
    ------+---------------+---------+-------------+
```

From which I want to achieve output like this:

```
    --------------+---------+---------+--------+------+--------------+----------
    | competitor  | Bowling | Quiz    |  Darts |Pool  |Treasure Hunt | Snooker | 
    --------------+---------+---------+--------+------+--------------+----------
    | Microsoft   | 12      |  11     |   23   |  0   | 0            | 0       |
    | BBC         | 66      |  12     |   11   |  23  | 66           | 23      |
    | Facebook    | 66      |  12     |   11   |  23  | 0            | 66      |
    --------------+---------+---------+--------+------+--------------+----------
```

I have tried all sorts of joins and nested php but I just can't crack it. I'm not even sure if it's possible. My SQL knowledge is not great, I've tried some tutorials but they don't cover this kind of query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your query by php like this

```
<?php
$events = array('Assume this is array of events table with id,eventName as key');

$column = array();
foreach($events as $event)
{
     $column[] = 'SUM(IF(results.eventId = '.$event['id'].', results.eventScore, 0)) AS '.$event['eventName'];
}

$sql = 'SELECT   competitors.competitorName AS competitor,';
$sql .= implode(',',$column);
$sql .= ' FROM competitors';
$sql .= ' LEFT JOIN results ON results.competitorId = competitors.id';
$sql .= ' GROUP BY competitors.id';
//Put $sql into mysql_query then
```

Then, to get row dynamically

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    foreach($row as $k=>$v) 
    {
         //Here you get Column Name as $k  and data value as $v
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bitoshi-n this almost works for my purposes but i cant retireve the scores without having to use harcdcoded values. I need these to be dyanmic as the events may change.                              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['competitor'] . " " . $row['Bowling']. $row['Darts'];
  echo "<br />";
}

Comment: @user1156756. Ok, so you can choose any accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer then.

Comment: Do you know how i could then ORDER BY so that the competitor row with the highest SUM score across the events will be the first returned record?

Comment: @user1156756 add `SUM(results.eventScore) AS sumScore` in the `select` field so you can order them by put `ORDER BY sumScore` in the query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   competitors.competitorName                          AS competitor,
         SUM(IF(results.eventId = 1, results.eventScore, 0)) AS Bowling,
         SUM(IF(results.eventId = 2, results.eventScore, 0)) AS Quiz,
         -- etc.
FROM     competitors
  LEFT JOIN results ON results.competitorId = competitors.id
GROUP BY competitors.id
```

Comment: More elegant than my answer !

Answer (score 1):

**This request is normally ok but need a modification each time a new entry is added in the table events.**

```
SELECT
    comp.competitorName as competitor,
    rbowling.eventScore as Bowling,
    rquiz.eventScore as Quiz,
    rdarts.eventScore as Darts,
    rpool.eventScore as Pool,
    rtreasure.eventScore as Treasure_Hunt,
    rsnooker.eventScore as Snooker
FROM competitors comp
LEFT JOIN result rbowling ON (rbowling.eventId = 1 AND comp.id = rbowling.competitorId)
LEFT JOIN result rquiz ON (rquiz.eventId = 2 AND comp.id = rquiz.competitorId)
LEFT JOIN result rdarts ON (rdarts.eventId = 3 AND comp.id = rdarts.competitorId)
LEFT JOIN result rpool ON (rpool.eventId = 4 AND comp.id = rpool.competitorId)
LEFT JOIN result rtreasure ON (rtreasure.eventId = 5 AND comp.id = rtreasure.competitorId)
LEFT JOIN result rsnooker ON (rsnooker.eventId = 6 AND comp.id = rsnooker.competitorId)
GROUP BY comp.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for a pivot table. There's an example and [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78).

Answer (score 0):

The query You are looking for is this one:

```
SELECT r.eventScore, e.eventName, c.competitorName
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id = r.eventId
LEFT JOIN competitors c ON c.id = r.competitorId
```

By this query You will get for each result the underlying event and competitor name.
Then You have to manage the data within PHP to create a table You desire... But I guess it woul be quite hard to achieve...

I would preferably do a select for competitors and events separately and then get all the score results and create a table like this:

```
// we have $competitors array containing id => name
// we have $events array containing id => name
// we have $results array containing competitorId => [ eventId => score ]
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Competitors</td>';
foreach($events as $e)
    echo '<td>'.$e.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach($results as $cId => $val) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$competitors[$cId].'</td>';
    foreach($events as $eId => $name) {
        echo '<td>'.$val[$eId].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

But this is just a quick and not very nice solution, I'd better go the way of one query.